# Pagination of MySQL results in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I never really considered this(pagination) as an issue until lately. When I sat down and zeroed in on it, I found myself facing plenty of problems.

What I am into is a basic contacts management system wherein a user can add/update/delete/search contacts. The search part is where I need the pagination to be implemented effectively.

What I have in mind (with +ve and -ve points)

- I can specify `pageNo` and `offset` while `POST`ing to my `search.php` page. This page will fire a simple MySQL query to retrieve the results. Since the number of rows can pretty much run in thousands, I need to paginate it. Quite simple, but I need to fire the *same* query again and again for every different page. Meaning, when a user goes from page1 to page2, the same MySQL query will be fired(of course with a different `offset`), which is something I feel is redundant, and am trying to avoid.
- Then I thought of capturing the **entire** set of result, and storing it into `$_SESSION`, but in this case, what if the results are just *huge*? Will it affect performance in any way?
- On similar lines like the second point, I thought of writing out the results on to a file, which is plain crap! (I just put it here, as a point. I know this is REAL bad way of doing things.)

My Questions:

**A**. Which of the above methods do I implement? Which one is better? Are there any other methods? I have googled it, but I find that most of the examples follow point1 above.

**B**. My questions for point1: How can we rely on the order of the mysql results? Suppose, the user navigates to page2 after some time, how can we be sure, that during the second time, the records of the first page arent repeated? (Because, we are doing a fresh query)..

**C**. What exactly is a MySQL resource? I understand that a `mysql_query(..)` returns a `resource`. Is it global in the sense that, it maintains the state between different calls to PHP script? (I can maintain the resource in a `$_SESSION`).

Thanks a million! :-)

PS: I know this is a pretty long question. I just tried to put across, in a concise way, whats going around in my head.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use your first suggestion. The one with offsets. It's the "standard" way of doing pagination. Putting the whole result set into session would be a bad idea, since every user would have his own private copy of the data. If you hit performance problems you can always add caching (memcache) which will benefit all users accessing the data.

MySQL will always result your data the same way. The only way that a record from page 1 would appear on page 2 is if a new record was inserted between the time that user navigates from page 1 to page 2. In other words: you have nothing to worry about.

A resource is MySQL's case is a pointer of sorts that points to the result set. You can then manipulate that (fetching data row by row, counting the number of rows returned etc). It is not global.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You are just spot on, in your second para. That was just the *exact* question in my mind.

And about the MySQL resource, yes, I do understand that it is a plain pointer identifying some internal resource. But what is the size of the `resource` type in bytes? Plus, is it maintained as long as MySQL service runs (so that I can populate further results in the next call to my PHP script) ?

Comment: Resource is just like any other variable in your PHP script. When the script finishes it no longer exists. The size of the resource, as far as I know, depends on the size of the data returned.

Comment: just to add to the value of this answer - have a look here for a possible pagination optimization technique: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/01/order-by-limit-performance-optimization/

Answer (score 1):

A. First one, of course. there are other methods, like for the every thing in the Earth, but like for the every thing on the Earth one have to use **most usual and generic way** first, just because they have to get familiar with it and because it will suit you for sure, as it suits other webmasters.
Also note that your other proposed methods are not among sensible ones.

B. yes, records do move across pages. Nothing bad in that.

C. Nothing in PHP maintains it's state between calls. No resource can be saved in a session. go for offset pagination.

Comment: @Shrapnel: The way you generally answer, I just LOL! :-)
BTW, Could you just elucidate your last point? I didnt really understand what you meant there. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

When constructing your SQL you can do something like the following (0 is the offset, 10 is how many rows to return)

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 0, 10
```

This will display the first 10 results from the database.

Alternative syntax, 3 queries, showing the first 30 results 1-10,11-20,21-30.

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20
```

Edit:

Okay, to clarify, option 1 is your best bet. Pass in page number. Limit is the same each query, and `$offset = ($pageNum - 1 ) * 10;`.

You will need an `ORDER BY` clause. However, if the contents of the database change between page loads there a user might notice discrepancies. It really depends on how frequently your data changes.

I've not tried to store the result of a mysql_query() in session. I would suspect not the way you are thinking of using it. As when the script ends you can consider mysql_close() to be called implicitly, and resources destroyed.

Comment: Thanks, but to be precise, my real question is a bit different. :-)

Comment: I've expanded upon it. Hope it helps.

Comment: You can change the formula to: `$offset = ($pageNum - 1) * $results`, where `$resultsNo` represents the result count per page. In the SQL: `SELECT * FROM {$your_table} LIMIT {$resultNo} OFFSET {$offset}`

Answer (score 1):

From my experience (which is not much), i usually used the first method, because each time you go to another page you will always get an updated data from mysql. Yes, if you're using order by last_updated_time then the result will move across pages.

But i think that's not what you have in your mind. As you mention in your third question, perhaps you want to have some kind of buffer for your results, but it means you'll have to create the buffer for every result (that's the reason you mention about using file to store mysql result).

probably this is the answer that you're looking for (if that could consider as an answer at all :LOL), but my purpose was just trying to give some perspective.