# Select records around a specific record from database

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry for a vague title, but if i had known how to formulate this in english - would've used google :) So here's the problem: let's say we have a query:

```
SELECT A.*, B.* FROM ... JOIN ... ORDER BY WHATEVER
```

What i basically need  to do is take this resultset and shrink it to a record with specific **A.id** + a few neighbouring records.

So for example if our resultset returns A.id =

```
1, 2, 3, (4, 5, 6, [7], 8, 9, 10), 11, 12
```

I basically need the part in (brackets) including the target record [7].

Since there might be a simple or a complex query involved and the ordering could differ, i can't just say "give me records id>=4 and id <= 10" so i need some sort of more complex solution.

A (perhaps) more clear and realistic example:

- there is a listing of 50 photos per page
- ordering and filtering available
- when you click on a photo on any page, there should be a navigation with other photos that would be around the clicked photo in the "paging" with the selected filters
- filters are session-stored so they are not a problem here

Comment: How you define a little more and a little less?

Comment: SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM x WHERE z >= n ORDER BY z) a UNION (SELECT WHERE z < n ORDER BY DESC) you get the idea

Comment: @Strawberry i think that might just work! move it to an answer and i'll accept it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pagination of MySQL results in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056101/pagination-of-mysql-results-in-php)

Comment: @BillGregg i don't think it has anything to do with pagination. It's is more of an extraction of a part of a paginated resultset

Comment: I think it is because you want to "SELECT * FROM ____ ORDER BY ____ LIMIT pageSize OFFSET firstRecord". Your example of photos in a page is certainly just a pagination question. When you first painted that photo page, you knew where you were in the result set, ie which page you were on.

Comment: @BillGregg it doesn't matter if i know the page index. The photo might be last in the page and that would mean i'd need to get some photos from page+1. Not to mention the fact that if you open a direct link to the photo, you don't really know which page it was on.

Comment: Keep up with which photo was clicked on. As you render the photos, number them, store their intra page index somewhere. Then when someone clicks on a particular photo "select * from _____ order by _____ limit pageSize OFFSET pageSize*pageIndex + intraPageIndex". You have to know where you are.

Comment: @BillGregg that would be possible, yes. But very difficult, as every user may have completely different filters (for filtering, ordering etc.) set and they might be comming to the photo directly without actually rendering the photos page. So it would be kinda hard to do, that's why i'm looking for an alternative way, with a single query.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (<your query here>) recs
     on t.id between recs.id - 3 and recs.id + 3;
```

Comment: cannot rely on ID, unfortunately. Or am i missing something with the "t.id" statement here?